# Convert an img to file and back in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine a web page has an *img* tag which needs to be uploaded. How do I convert this to a file object, so that I can send it over?

And on the other end, I have the hypothetical img, converted to file and sent to me. How do I convert this to a HTML tag?

I have an initial starting point for the latter part:

```
imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = imageUrl;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just send the image URL to the server, and then use the serverside to fetch the actual image ?

Comment: I'm trying something crooked. Imagine the server from which the image originated is now down or has crashed. And only my web page has the image. The URL would be practically useless in such a scenario, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you alredy have your image loaded in html page, you can encode it to base64, then send it to your server by ajax call and save it

**Javascript**

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
  // Create an empty canvas element
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  // Copy the image contents to the canvas
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  // Get the data-URL formatted image
  // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
  // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
  // will re-encode the image.
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/yourPage.aspx/YourWebMethod",
  data: "{yourParameterName:'" + JSON.stringify(getBase64Image(yourAlreadyLoadedImage)) + "'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
      async: false,
  success: function (data) {
    var result = data.d;
  },
  error: function () { alert('/yourPage.aspx/YourWebMethod'); }
});
```

Server side you can decode base64 image and save it, for example, in JPEG

**C#**

```
public void Base64ToImage(string coded)
{
  System.Drawing.Image finalImage;
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(coded);
  using(var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes)) {
    finalImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

  }

   finalImage.Save(yourFilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

}
```

Comment: Would have up-voted you, but sadly lack the reputation.

Comment: One can use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) to send blobs (`canvas.toBlob()`).